# Google maps api v2 android not showing for not admin account in device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have added the use of "Google Maps Android API v2" in my app. Test on the tablet Google Nexus 7. Everything works fine when the application is run under the account owner of the device. But if I create a new account, enter into it, and run the application, the map is not displayed. Has anyone encountered this problem? What to do?

P.S. I'm sorry for my english

**EDIT**
exception in log

```
09-25 11:49:34.169: ERROR/Google Maps Android API(31316): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
09-25 11:49:34.169: ERROR/Google Maps Android API(31316): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: ru.cmlt, API Key: *my api key*, Certificate Fingerprint: *my certificate fingerprint*
09-25 11:49:34.169: INFO/Google Maps Android API(31316): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
09-25 11:49:49.339: ERROR/Google Maps Android API(31316): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I tried to regenerate the API key, but it did not help. Internet connection is active and Google Play Services app is install

**EDIT2**
if the app installed in admin account, in other accounts app work fine. But if app installed only in additional account maps not working.

Comment: That should not happened, i would say its related to your API keys have you generated 2 keys (debug key & Release key) for your application

Comment: are you getting any exception when logging with different account? if yes post here

Comment: A stupid mistake was when I tried to debug my app and I didn't left myself any messages if there was not an internet connection. So my device was not connected to the internet but I didn't noticed that and the map was blank. I lost a half an hour until I noticed that. So I don't think it is an authentication problem but a network problem, be sure you are connected to the internet.

Comment: well the last line is pointing it out --> This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: Internet is available absolutely for sure. In addition to maps page has text and images, and they are normally downloaded from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Not the problem here, but since I had trouble noticing this and looked all over the web:

Note that there are two services to enable: "Google Maps Android API v2" and "Google Maps API v2". Make sure to pick the first one!

Comment: I use "Google Maps Android API v2".